# Jest mock not used - normal method is run instead

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I have the following setup to tests async functions.

Firstly, my folder structure:

```
src/
├── App.vue
├── api
│   ├── __mocks__
│   │   └── api.js
│   └── api.js
├── components
│   ├── ...
├── main.js
└── store
    ├── __tests__
    │   └── actions.spec.js
    ├── actions.js
    ├── getters.js
    ├── index.js
    ├── mutation-types.js
    └── mutations.js
```

Then my `actions.spec.js`:

```
import * as types from '@/store/mutation-types';
import api from '@/api/api';
import {
  fetchItems,
  requestItems,
  saveQuestion,
  vote,
} from '../actions';

jest.mock('@api/api');

describe('fetchItems Action', () => {
  let state;
  let commit;
  let dispatch;
  beforeAll(() => {
    commit = jest.fn();
    dispatch = jest.fn();
    state = {
      apiEntryPoint: '',
      nextPage: 0,
    };
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchItems({
      commit,
      dispatch,
      state,
    });
  });

  it('should call a commit before fetching', () => {
    expect(commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(types.PRE_HTTP_REQUEST);
  });

  it('should call receiveItems after succesful fetch', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('receiveItems', {});
    });
  });

  it('should call a fail commit if request fails', () => {
    api.fetchItems = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject());
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(types.FETCHED_ADS_FAIL);
    });
  });
});
```

`api/api.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://polls.apiblueprint.org/';

const getUrl = () => (
  axios('/')
    .then(response => response.data.questions_url)
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    })
);

const fetchItems = (url, page = 1) => (
  axios(url, { params: { page } })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    })
);
export default {
  fetchItems, getUrl,
};
```

and the `api/__mocks__/api.js`

```
const getUrl = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());

const fetchItems = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());

export default {
  fetchItems, getUrl
};
```

My issues:

1. by using the debugger it doesn't look like the mock methods are run
2. my output looks like a real HTTP req is done:

> PASS  src/components/QuestionsList/QuestionsList.spec.js
>        PASS  src/components/Question/Question.spec.js
>       (node:48568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 9): Error: Error: Network Error
>       (node:48568) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code.
>       (node:48568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 10): Error: Error: Network Error
>        PASS  src/store/**tests**/actions.spec.js

3. my tests PASS even if I change the arguments of "`toHaveBeenCalledWith()`" with other random arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In your test with a setTimeout, you need to use the `done` callback.

Currently, Jest is running the test and reaching the end without an error. To Jest, this means the test has passed. One way to get Jest to run the test asynchronously is to use the `done` callback.

If a test has the done callback, Jest won't pass the test until the done callback has been called.

Your code should look like this:

```
it('should call a fail commit if request fails', (done) => {
  api.fetchItems = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject());
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(types.FETCHED_ADS_FAIL);
    done()
  });
});
```

You can read about the [done callback in the Jest docs(http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#callbacks).

There are a few other ways that Jest deals with [asynchronous code](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html).

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone comes across this and needs to build a solution to fail when this happens, here is I've solved this: [Handle UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning Errors](https://medium.com/@chris.washington_60485/vue-jest-properly-catch-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-and-vue-warn-errors-in-jest-unit-tests-fcc45269146b?)